# SyntaxError: invalid syntax on very simple file from begginer

Tags: python, syntax-error

Hi I'm starting to code with pyhton and this message appears when I run a simple test: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

the code is the following:

###########################

```
numero_entero = 1
print(numero_entero)

numero_decimal = 2.46
print(numero_decimal)

numero_entero = numero_entero + 2
print(numero_entero)
```

#########################

Further on the error:

```
">>> & C:/Users/34664/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Coding/PYTHON/learning course/tiposDeDatosYOperadores"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/34664/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Coding/PYTHON/learning course/tiposDeDatosYOperadores"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not valid Python code. Try moving the print() calls to separate lines

Comment: `>>>` indicates you try to run the file from the inetractive shell. You need to run the file from cmd